Which temple sacrifices was Jesus making during his lifetime?
Of course there would be no sin atonement offering, but there were the other sacrifices that had nothing to do with sin. If Jesus in fact followed the law perfectly, He would have had to have made some of these following sacrifices it would seem.
Sacrifices were for peace offerings, fellowship offerings, votive offerings, offerings of consecration.
In John 7 Jesus attends Sukkot and is in the crowd during the water libation ceremony.
Jesus also instructs a man healed with leprosy to go to the temple and make a sacrifice, probably of thanksgiving.
In Matthew 17 Jesus pays the temple tax with a coin found in a fish that Peter catches.
This is merely a question for intellectual speculation since the scriptures don't define them.

Welcome to the site, interesting question... Um, I think he would have made them, but not as an adult? Hmm...

People were required to bring their own personal sin atonement to the priests if they had sinned. Jesus never sinned so he wouldn't have had to do a personal sin atonement. However He was present at at least 29 national sin atonements for Israel during his lifetime. But there are other temple sacrifices that have nothing to do with sin. He would have been involved in those as well I would think

He would have been present for each sacrifice that was required, as well as the ones his parents were at (so for Joseph's offerings, as a parent would teach a child about it), the national ones, but he would have very likely not gone to a single "extra" ritual or sacrifice that the pharisees or their ilk had added. (Think of how the law of Moses was possible for a poor person to maintain, and how the pharisees were admonished for making the poor life even harder)... I hate to say this is kinda of speculation as an answer but I'll see if I can dig up anything from church fathers.

after all, they did debate with Jews so maybe there is something to be found that could answer :)

the last sentence This is merely a question for intellectual speculation since the scriptures don't define them. makes this opinion based

It sure does except someone is working to find anything written by church Fathers which makes it valid. Flag it if it makes you feel good

Ah, don't use me for validation. I am not devoting full power to this question. I've not found much from re-reading debates between early church fathers and the rabbi of that era. And I am reading that stuff because I started to delve into the subject of "anti-jew" and "anti-christian" sentiments during the 50-300AD period. I'm sure there is a tradition answer somewhere... but I've not found it. I've only got it in the back of my mind, IF i see something.
